# ld lookup to find library

Tags: c++, build-process, ld

I'm cross compiling to an arm embedded system and receiving an error that I have questions about. Here is the error:

```
[ 19%] Built target cxjpeg-6b
Linking CXX shared library /home/botbear/JAUS++-2.110519-   src/libraries/jaus++/2.0/lib/libcxutils.so
/home/botbear/openwrt/trunk/staging_dir/toolchain-arm_v6k_gcc-linaro_uClibc-    0.9.32_eabi/lib/gcc/arm-openwrt-linux-uclibcgnueabi/4.5.4/../../../../arm-openwrt-linux-    uclibcgnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lpng 
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/botbear/JAUS++-2.110519-src/libraries/jaus++/2.0/lib/libcxutils.so]     Error 1
make[1]: *** [libcxutils/CxUtils/libcxutils/CMakeFiles/cxutils.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

As you can see the linker is looking for a static library named 'libpng'.  In addition to the libpng lib., the command in the sub-make file using the -l switch to link to the following libraries: -lpng -lz -lX11 -lXtst -lpthread -Wl.  All of the libraries (libpng,libz,libX11, etc) are in my host /usr/lib/ directory but my target toolchain does not have the the libraries.  My question is if I manually recompile the libraries with my target compiler will that solved my problem? Or I'm going to have find and install packages for each of the libraries for my target platform.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: probably. But recompiling X11 is not a trivial task.

Comment: you need to have all the dependencies compiled for your target architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to compile for the target, so you need target libraries. Either compiled by yourself or provided by the toolchain development environment (if you have one). The latter usually saves you some headaches (cross compiling and setting the paths where necessary).

I see you are using openwrt toolchain. Openwrt seems to have libpng as a package. I'd go with that if possible.

Comment: Thanks!  I will search for lib packages.